# Api Rest Vertx Java Login Keycloak Error io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.cachePermission

Tags: java, api, keycloak, vert.x

I am integrating a REST service for user login found in keycloak to an existing java project, testing it in a new project works correctly for me but when I try to integrate it to the existing project it throws this error `io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2 .impl.OAuth2UserImpl.cachePermission.`

```
public class KeyCloakVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

@Override
public void start() {

    JsonObject keycloakJson = new JsonObject()
            .put("realm", "master")
            .put("realm-public-key", "<public_key>")
            .put("auth-server-url", "http://localhost:8080/auth")
            .put("ssl-required", "external")
            .put("resource", "api-vertx-keycloak") 
            .put("credentials", new JsonObject().put("secret", "<secret>"));

    OAuth2Auth oauth2 = KeycloakAuth.create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.PASSWORD, keycloakJson);

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route("/protected/*").handler(ResponseContentTypeHandler.create());
    router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/protected").handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").handler(BodyHandler.create());

    router.post("/login").produces("application/json").handler(rc -> {
        System.err.println("received body ::: '"+rc.getBodyAsString()+"'");
        JsonObject userJson = rc.getBodyAsJson();
        System.err.println("User ::: "+userJson.encode());

        oauth2.authenticate(userJson, res -> {
            if (res.failed()) {
                System.err.println("Access token error: {} " + res.cause().getMessage());
                rc.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.code()).end();
            } else {
                User user = res.result();
                System.out.println("Success: we have found user: "+user.principal().encodePrettily());
                rc.response().end(user.principal().encodePrettily());
            }
        });
    });

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8082);

}
```

}

> io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.cachePermission(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.cachePermission(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.init(OAuth2UserImpl.java:79)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.setAuthProvider(OAuth2UserImpl.java:91)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2UserImpl.(OAuth2UserImpl.java:40)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2TokenImpl.(OAuth2TokenImpl.java:55)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.flow.PasswordImpl.lambda$getToken$0(PasswordImpl.java:57)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.flow.AbstractOAuth2Flow.lambda$getToken$0(AbstractOAuth2Flow.java:142)
>       at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2API.lambda$null$1(OAuth2API.java:129)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl$BodyHandler.notifyHandler(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:299)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.lambda$bodyHandler$0(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:189)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleEnd(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:253)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection$StreamImpl.endResponse(Http1xClientConnection.java:416)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection.handleResponseEnd(Http1xClientConnection.java:496)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientHandler.handleMessage(Http1xClientHandler.java:118)
>       at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientHandler.handleMessage(Http1xClientHandler.java:32)
>       at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.lambda$channelRead$1(VertxHandler.java:146)
>       at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
>       at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
>       at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:144)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Try to setup logging (log4j2 for example)
if you prefer to use System.out then you should use 
res.cause().printStackTrace() and paste stack trace here

Comment: check dependency versions for new project and existing, which vert.x version you use, also check if oauth dependency has correct version